# I get so many errors I don't know what I'm doing wrong, in my Java program

Tags: java

You'll just have to run it yourself everything goes wrong when I hit calculate.

This is all the errors I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at school.TravelExpenses$CalcButtonListener.actionPerformed(TravelExpenses.java:139)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Code:

```
package school;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * The TravelExpense class creates the GUI for the Travel Expenses application.
 */

public class TravelExpenses extends JFrame {
    // The following variables will reference the
    // custom panel objects
    private JPanel travelInfoPanel; // TravelInfo panel
    private JPanel buttonPanel; // Buttons panel

    // Labels for the Travel Information fields.
    private JLabel DaysLabel;
    private JLabel AirfareLabel;
    private JLabel CarLabel;
    private JLabel MilesLabel;
    private JLabel ParkingLabel;
    private JLabel CabLabel;
    private JLabel RegistrLabel;
    private JLabel LodgingLabel;

    // Text Fields for Travel Information entry
    private JTextField DaysTextField;
    private JTextField AirfareTextField;
    private JTextField CarTextField;
    private JTextField MilesTextField;
    private JTextField ParkingTextField;
    private JTextField CabTextField;
    private JTextField RegistrTextField;
    private JTextField LodgingTextField;

    private JButton calcButton;

    private double mealsReimbursed = 37.00;
    private double parkingReimbursed = 10.00;
    private double taxiChargesReimbursed = 20.00;
    private double lodgingChargesReimbursed = 95.00;
    private double perMileReimbursed = 0.27;
    public TravelExpenses() {
        super("Travel Expenses");

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        buildTravelInfoPanel();
        buildButtonPanel();

        add(travelInfoPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }


    private void buildTravelInfoPanel() {
        DaysLabel = new JLabel("Number of days on trip: ");
        AirfareLabel = new JLabel("Amount of airfare: ");
        CarLabel = new JLabel("Amount of car rental: ");
        MilesLabel = new JLabel("Miles driven: ");
        ParkingLabel = new JLabel("Parking Fees: ");
        CabLabel = new JLabel("Taxi fees: ");
        RegistrLabel = new JLabel("Conference registration: ");
        LodgingLabel = new JLabel("Lodging charges per night: ");

        DaysTextField = new JTextField(3);
        AirfareTextField = new JTextField(8);
        CarTextField = new JTextField(8);
        MilesTextField = new JTextField(4);
        ParkingTextField = new JTextField(6);
        CabTextField = new JTextField(6);
        RegistrTextField = new JTextField(8);
        LodgingTextField = new JTextField(6);

        travelInfoPanel = new JPanel();

        travelInfoPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 2));

        travelInfoPanel.add(DaysLabel);
        travelInfoPanel.add(DaysTextField);
        travelInfoPanel.add(AirfareLabel);
        travelInfoPanel.add(AirfareTextField);
        travelInfoPanel.add(CarLabel);
        travelInfoPanel.add(CarTextField);
        travelInfoPanel.add(MilesLabel);
        travelInfoPanel.add(MilesTextField);
        travelInfoPanel.add(ParkingLabel);
        travelInfoPanel.add(ParkingTextField);
        travelInfoPanel.add(CabLabel);
        travelInfoPanel.add(CabTextField);
        travelInfoPanel.add(RegistrLabel);
        travelInfoPanel.add(RegistrTextField);
        travelInfoPanel.add(LodgingLabel);
        travelInfoPanel.add(LodgingTextField);

        // Add an empty border around the panel for spacing.
        travelInfoPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory
                .createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 1, 10));
    }

    private void buildButtonPanel() {
        // Create the calcButton.
        calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");

        calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        buttonPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        // Add the two buttons to the buttonPanel.
        buttonPanel.add(calcButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 10, 10, 10));
    }

    private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        String days = DaysTextField.getText();
        String air = AirfareTextField.getText();
        String carRental = CarTextField.getText();
        String miles = MilesTextField.getText();
        String parking =ParkingTextField.getText();
        String taxi = CabTextField.getText();
        String Registr = RegistrTextField.getText();
        String lodging = LodgingTextField.getText();

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Declare variables for calculated items
            double actualExpenses=Double.valueOf(air) + Double.valueOf(carRental) + Double.valueOf(parking) + Double.valueOf(taxi) + Double.valueOf(Registr) + Double.valueOf(lodging) + (Double.valueOf(miles)*.27);
            double allowableExpenses=(mealsReimbursed+parkingReimbursed+taxiChargesReimbursed+lodgingChargesReimbursed)*Integer.valueOf(days)+perMileReimbursed;
            double excessAmount=actualExpenses-allowableExpenses;
            String savedMoney="Owed";
            if(excessAmount<0){
                savedMoney="Saved";
                excessAmount*=-1;
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Expenses: "+actualExpenses+"\nAllowable Expenses: "+allowableExpenses+"\n"+"Money "+savedMoney+": "+excessAmount);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TravelExpenses();
    }
}
```

Comment: `NumberFormatException: empty String` seems pretty clear.  The problem originates at `school.TravelExpenses$CalcButtonListener.actionPerformed(TravelExpenses.java:139)` within your code

Comment: Sorry about some of the confusing comments It's fairly messy as I've been trying many things in my endeavors to fix it

Comment: You could also take a look at [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) which perform their own validation internally

Comment: And, of course, `double` is not the ideal data type to use for storing and manipulating amounts of money.  You might consider using `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: So thanks to you guys I figured out that its just not taking whats in the text fields and putting them in the variables.

Comment: Please do work on "You'll Just have to run it yourself everything goes wrong when I hit calculate".

Answer (score 1):

That is just one error, showing the stack of methods that were called to get to it.

The problem is that you are attempting to parse a number from an empty string. The problem is in this line:

```
double actualExpenses=Double.valueOf(air) + Double.valueOf(carRental) + Double.valueOf(parking) + Double.valueOf(taxi) + Double.valueOf(Registr) + Double.valueOf(lodging) + (Double.valueOf(miles)*.27);
```

One of the following variables contains an empty string:

```
air
carRental
parking
taxi
Registr
lodging
miles
```

This is because the values from all of your text fields are only being retrieved when the ActionListener is being created, not when the action is being performed. If you move all of your `*Field.getText()` calls inside the `actionPerformed()` method, this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that this

```
String air = AirfareTextField.getText();
```

only executes once.  This is executed when you create the listener, not each time.

You need to move this into the action method so that it is run each time you change the text.

Comment: It's all the `*Field.getText()` calls, not just `AirfareTextField.getText()`.